# Copy-On-Write : What status after father and son modify the page?

Tags: memory, fork, virtual-memory, copy-on-write, page-tables

When you fork a process, at the beggining, father and son share the same memory page. But if one of them write on this page, it is duplicated so that the first one is not affected by this change. That's roughly what is called Copy-on-Write.

My question is : What happens if we fork() a process, then the child modify the page: the page is duplicate once, but **after that, the father ALSO modify the page**. Is the page duplicated again? Does the father "know" that is only son already duplicated?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

(Generic at the risk of oversimplification -- IE how it COULD work)

```
Parent process has Virtual Page 10 as readwrite physical page 1000.
Parent process has Virtual Page 11 as readwrite physical page 1001.
```

Parent forks child.

```
Parent process has Virtual Page 10 as readonly physical page 1000.
Parent process has Virtual Page 11 as readonly physical page 1001.
Child process has Virtual Page 10 as readonly physical page 1000.
Child process has Virtual Page 11 as readonly physical page 1001.
```

Parent write to Virtual Page 10.
Triggers a protection fault.
OS detects it is a copy on write page
Copies physical page 1000 to 1002
Decrements reference count to physical page 1000
restarts instruction

```
Parent process has Virtual Page 10 as readwrite physical page 1002.
Parent process has Virtual Page 11 as readonly physical page 1001.
Child process has Virtual Page 10 as readonly physical page 1000.
Child process has Virtual Page 11 as readonly physical page 1001.
```

Child write to virtual page 11
Triggers a protection fault.
OS detects it is a copy on write page
Copies physical page 1001 to 1003
Decrements reference count to physical page 1001
restarts instruction

```
Parent process has Virtual Page 10 as readwrite physical page 1002.
Parent process has Virtual Page 11 as readonly physical page 1001.
Child process has Virtual Page 10 as readonly physical page 1000.
Child process has Virtual Page 11 as readwrite physical page 1003.
```

Parent writes to virtual page 11
Triggers a protection fault.
OS detects it is a copy on write page AND that the reference count is 1.
OS changes the page to readwrite
restarts instruction

```
Parent process has Virtual Page 10 as readwrite physical page 1002.
Parent process has Virtual Page 11 as readwrite physical page 1001.
Child process has Virtual Page 10 as readonly physical page 1000.
Child process has Virtual Page 11 as readwrite physical page 1003.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are n processes having access to a copy-on-write page, with n ≥ 2. If one process writes, the page is copied and becomes a normal page for that process. The original page is now shared n-1 times only; if n = 1 then it becomes a normal page as well. There would be no point in making two copies.